# About relative normalization in Deligne's definition of a "tangential morphism"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I'm reading Deligne's paper "Le Groupe Fondamental de la Droite Projective Moins Trois Points", specifically in the section "Theorie profinie" (sections 15.13 - 15.27)

I'm specifically interested in 15.19, where he says (I had to fix some apparent typos):

More generally, let $\overline{X}$ be a smooth morphism of relative dimension 1 over a normal scheme $B$, and $S$ a divisor of $X$ etale over $B$. Let $X := \overline{X} - S$,and $Y$ a tamely ramified cover of $X$. We may extend $Y$ to a finite map $\pi : \overline{Y}\rightarrow\overline{X}$, where $\overline{Y}$ is smooth over $B$, the preimage $S_Y$ of $S$ in $\overline{Y}$ is etale over $B$, and the "principal part" of $\pi : \overline{Y}\rightarrow\overline{X}$ along $S_Y$ is a finite etale morphism between relative tangent spaces punctured at the origin.

**My question is:** How does he construct this scheme $\overline{Y}$? It seems to me that $\overline{Y}$ should be the normalization of $\overline{X}$ in $Y$, but I don't see (1) why this is smooth over $B$, and (2) why $S_Y$ is finite etale over $B$.

I would very much appreciate any insights into this.

I'd also appreciate any relevant references.

EDIT: I think I can make progress on this if I can prove that $\overline{Y}$ (defined as the normalization of $\overline{X}$ in $Y$) is flat and of finite presentation over $B$.

EDIT: Currently having difficulty regarding purity. Ie, is it possible for $\overline{Y}$ to be unramified over $\overline{X}$ in codimension 1, but is somehow ramified at codimension $\ge 2$ points lying over $S$? In fact, since genus is constant in flat families, if $\overline{Y}$ were to be flat over $B$, then this shouldn't be able to happen (at least when $\overline{X}$ is an elliptic curve over $B$)

Comment: Relative Abyhankar Lemma in the case of relative dimension 1; see Prop. 5.5 in Exp. XIII of SGA1 (briefly, that gives an etale-local description which is well-suited to checking that normalization has the properties you seek, as normalization commutes with etale base change).  Note you can assume B is strictly henselian and local, and then can reduce to where S is a section.

Comment: @nfdc23 Thanks for your comment! Though, I'm probably being stupid, but I'm a little confused about how Prop 5.5 gives an etale-local description of the normalization, since the relevant morphism seems to be $X_1'\rightarrow X_1$, which is not etale. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: All I meant is that passing to strict henselization commutes with normalization (I am viewing strict henselization as a limit of local-etale neighborhoods, and one of which can be "spread out" a bit), and with the description over strict henselization as in SGA1 one can aim to compute a normalization by bare hands to verify some properties of interest.

Comment: @nfdc23 It seems one obstacle is that the results you cited only seem to give descriptions over *regular* strict henselian local rings. I *think* I can use that to show that the fibers of $\overline{Y}$ over $S$ (I define $\overline{Y}$ as the normalization of $\overline{X}$ in $Y$) are smooth. However, I would still need flatness and finite presentedness to deduce that $\overline{Y}$ is smooth over $S$.

Comment: Codimension-1 points of the normal base are regular, so you can apply the relative Abyhankar Lemma there. Ramification indices are units on $B$ (can check in codimension 1, by normality). Hence, it suffices that for normal local $B$, $B$-smooth $A$, and regular $a \in A$ with $A/aA=B$, that $C:=A_P[T]/(T^e-a)$ (finite flat over $A_P$!) is normal for $e>0$ in $B^{\times}$ and $P$ containing $a$. Note that $A_P$ inherits normality from $B$, so by Serre's normality criterion $C$ inherits S$_2$ from $A_P$.  But $C$ satisfies R$_1$ since it reduces to $A_P$ a field or dvr (use $e\in A_P^{\times}$).

Comment: @nfdc23 here P is a height 1 prime of A?

Comment: No, definitely not.  (When I speak of "regular $a \in A$" I mean $a$ is not a zero-divisior in $A$, nothing about regularity of $A$, by the way.) So $A_P$ may not be regular.  But to verify R$_1$ it suffices to work on localizations of $A_P$ at its own primes of height $\le 1$.

Comment: @nfdc23 So what is P then?

Comment: It is any prime ideal of $A$.

Comment: @nfdc23 Months ago I thought I had a proof, though upon revisiting it, I'm finding that it doesn't work. Here's my problem: Firstly, using the fiberwise criterion for flatness we can reduce to the situation where the extension of function fields is Galois, so we can split the cover into a totally ramified map$\overline{Y}\rightarrow \overline{Y}'$ followed by a map which is unramified in codim 1 $\overline{Y}'\rightarrow\overline{X}$...

Comment: @nfdc23  I think I can prove flatness of the totally ramified part, but for the unramified part, I feel like I need some kind of purity result. Ie., let A be a strict local ring centered at a closed point $x$ on the divisor $S$, and let $f : \overline{Y}'\rightarrow \overline{X}$ be the above map which is unramified in codim 1. Let $d := deg(f)$, then if the pullback of $\overline{Y}'$ to Spec $A$ has $d$ closed points, then maybe I can say that each must be a copy of Spec $A$, and hence the map is flat at $x$. However, I don't see how I can rule out the possibility of ramification at $x$ ...